# Using ranges and sets in Visual Basic

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 same matrix. They have cells: first matrix has a11, a12, ... , aij cells, second b11, b12, ... , bij cells. I need to write a formula `=A11*B11 + A12*B12 + A13*B13 ... + Aij*Bij`, and so on until the right down corner of matrix. I wanted to do macros for not wasting time when matrix 10 x 10, because writing such a formula 100 times takes very long time. I have code:

```
Sub myMacros()
  'where to
  Dim form As String
  form = "="

'Choose cell where to put formula
Dim whereToPutFormula As Range
Set whereToPutFormula = Application.InputBox("Choose cell where to put formula", Type:=8)

'Range of first and second matrix
Dim firstMatrix As Range

Set firstMatrix = Application.InputBox("Range of the first matrix", Type:=8)
Dim secondMatrix As Range
Set secondMatrix = Application.InputBox("Range of the second matrix", Type:=8)

col_number = InputBox("How many columns in matrix")
row_number = InputBox("How many rows in matrix")

'variables for loop
Dim Rows As Integer
Dim Columns As Integer

'loop for formula
For Rows = 1 To row_number
    For Columns = 1 To col_number
        'val_from_firstMatrix = Range(firstMatrix).Cells().Value2
        'val_from_secondMatrix = Range(secondMatrix).Cells().Value2
        If Rows = row_number And Columns = col_number Then
            form = form & Range(firstMatrix).Cells(Rows, Columns).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False) & "*"
            form = form & Range(secondMatrix).Cells(Rows, Columns).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
            Debug.Print form
        Else:
            form = form & Range(firstMatrix).Cells(Rows, Columns).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False) & "*"
            form = form & Range(secondMatrix).Cells(Rows, Columns).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False) & " + "
            Debug.Print form
        End If
    Next Columns
Next Rows

End Sub
```

But it returns an error

> error 1004, Method 'Range' of object '_Global' field.

on if condition. What should I change for it to work?

Comment: What is the error it gives you?

Comment: @braX runtime error 1004, Method 'Range' of object '_Global' field. It is in the condition in the loop

Comment: Don't use special, reserved for VBA, names for variables like `Rows` and `Columns`. Change it for something else and your problems will gone.

Comment: @Teamothy I changed Rows to r and Columns to c and nothing changed. I presume thats because I use Set in Range..

Comment: Your question is confusing to me. It seems you have overlaying matrices (10x10 with one starting in column A and the second in Column B).  Presumably your error is on the line that contains `Range(firstMatrix)`.  `firstMatrix` is a `Range` object.  The argument for the `Range` object, used in this manner, needs to be the **NAME** of a range, **not** another `Range object.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld you mean that instead Range(firstMatrix).Cells.... I should use firstMatrix.Cells... ? Or how could I do it

Comment: @Alexey If the error is on that line, that is one way to eliminate that error.

Comment: @Alexey Also note that the formula in your question: `=A11*B11 + A12*B12 + A13*B13` is equivalent to:  `=SUMPRODUCT(A11:A13,B11:B13)`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld so I have no need to do this 2 loops, I just can `=SUMPRODUCT(A11:Aij,B11:Bij)` and it will do `A11*B11 + A12*B12 + ...` until the right down corner of the matrix?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld write is as an answer. I will accept it, that is what I tried to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on our discussion in comments, I post the following:

Your question is confusing to me. It seems you have overlaying matrices (`10x10` with one starting in `A11` and the second `B11`?).

Presumably your error is on the line that contains `Range(firstMatrix)`. `firstMatrix` is a `Range` object. The argument for the `Range` object, used in this manner, needs to be the **NAME** of a range, **not** another Range object.

Also note that the formula in your question: `=A11*B11 + A12*B12 + A13*B13` is equivalent to: `=SUMPRODUCT(A11:A13,B11:B13)`

If your matrices were just single columns, that would be the same as

```
`=SUMPRODUCT(A11:An,B11:Bn)
```